# ColdFusion .net integration service - unable to locate endpoint .net dll

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dll, coldfusion

I have a .net class library dll that has a Service reference. The endpoint is specified in the app.config file like this

```
endpoint address="blah .. blah" 
behaviorConfiguration="ClientCertificateBehavior" 
binding="wsHttpBinding" 
bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IAuthnService"
contract="AuthnService.IAuthnService" 
name="WSHttpBinding_IAuthnService"
```

So when the dll is built a .dll.config file is also generated.

The .dll is used/invoked from within Coldfusion 10 like this

```
<cfobject  
    type=".NET" 
    name="MyInstance" 
    class="DavitaUserAuthentication.Main" 
    assembly="path/assembly name" >
<cfset myXMLData =MyInstance.TestServiceMethod("#param1#","#param2#")>
```

I am getting the following error.

> "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'AuthnService.IAuthnService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. **This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element**."

However, when I call any other method on the dll that does not use the service reerence. Its working fine.

Is there a way to register the config file with the CF server.

Mayuresh

Comment: Just wanted to update everyone we have been able to solve the issue with he config file. The .net service, when it starts, will read the config file located at C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\jnbridge\JNBDotNetSide.exe.config C:\ColdFusion9\jnbridge\JNBDotNetSide.exe.config . Add the entire <system.serviceModel> tag form the <name>.dll.config here. This way the .net dll will have the endpoint it needs to look up.